# Why is the .NET Framework 4.8.1 Runtime Offline Installer significantly smaller than the 4.8.0 release?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-4.8

I downloaded the .NET Framework 4.8 and 4.8.1 Runtime Offline installers from the links below.

It seems strange that 4.8.1 is significantly smaller (by 44 Megabytes).

.Net Framework 4.8.1 = 77 Mbs
.Net Framework 4.8 = 121 Mbs

Were some libraries or something else eliminated in the 4.8.1 release vs 4.8?

I checked a blog article "Announcing .NET Framework 4.8.1" and did not see any mention of deletions.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481/

---

Download .NET Framework 4.8
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48

Download .NET Framework 4.8.1
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481

Comment: One reason could be because 4.8.1 drops support for older Windows versions. 4.8 supported Windows 7, 8, and Windows 10 versions prior to 2020H2, while 4.8.1 doesn't: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-net-framework-4-8/

Comment: @mamift - Thanks and I think that is probably the reason. I didn't realize 4.8.1 was dropping older OS support and that is good to know since my software is still offered to users on those OS levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mamift answered in comment above
"One reason could be because 4.8.1 drops support for older Windows versions. 4.8 supported Windows 7, 8, and Windows 10 versions prior to 2020H2, while 4.8.1 doesn't: devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-net-framework-4-8"

Accepting that answer and marking this question closed.